# Migration to GA4. What will happen when I call window.ga on July 1st?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I understand that google analytics UA properties will no longer receive events come July 1st when everyone will be moved to GA4. However, I have custom events using the google analytics UA site method `window.ga` what will happen when I call this function in the browser on July 1st ? Javascript error ?